# Why we use mixins rather than global functions in dart?

Tags: flutter, oop, dart

In dart programming language we have mixins which basically are pack of reusable codes. like when we need to add a functionality to our class we use mixins. Imagine have a function like that:

```
void endSession {
     print('end');
}
```

if we define this function in a file like `end_session_handler.dart` we can use this function all over the app in every classes. but with mixins in dart we basically do the same thing with lots of boilerplate codes! like that in `end_session_mixin`:

```
mixin CanEndSession {
     void endSession{
          print('end');
     }
}
```

and in a class which we want use this code we write:

```
class Example with CanEndSession {
     endSession();
}
```

Why we should use mixins rather than global functions in our apps?

Comment: You would use them if you want your class to conform to an interface specified by the mixin.